# Loop over columns in dataframe to produce plots with ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with factor and numeric variables. Herewith displayed are the first few rows and columns.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  cluster SEV_D SEV_M   OBS   PAN  
    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>
1       1     5     1    0     1    
2       2     6     1    0     0    
3       1     5     1    0     1    
4       2     4     2    0     0    
5       1     4     1    1     1    
6       1     4     2    1     0   

cluster=as.factor(c(1,2,1,2,1,1))
SEV_D=as.numeric(c(5,6,5,4,4,4))
SEV_M=as.numeric(c(1,1,1,2,1,2))
OBS=as.factor(c(0,0,0,0,1,1))
PAN=as.factor(c(1,0,1,0,1,0))
a<-data.frame(cluster,SEV_D,SEV_M,OBS,PAN)
```

I would like a number of graphs collected in the same sheet, one sheet for factor variables (OBS,PAN), one for numeric variables (SEV_D,SEV_M), the variable 'cluster' would be used for grouping. Here is the snippet of codes I have come up so far which would allow me to produce the single plots.

```
data_fact <- data[, sapply(data, class) == 'factor']
```

to subset 'factor' variables

```
data_cont <- data[, sapply(data, class) == 'numeric' | names(data) == 
"cluster"]
```

to subset numeric variables and 'cluster' which will be used for grouping.

An example of code for OBS

```
ggplot(data_fact,aes(x=cluster,fill=OBS))+geom_bar(position = 
position_dodge())
```

An example of code for SEV_D

```
data_cont %>% group_by(cluster) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(SEV_D), sd = sd(SEV_D)) %>% 
ggplot(.,aes(x=cluster,y=mean))+geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), 
stat="identity",colour="black",size=.3)+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, 
ymax=mean+sd),size=.3,width=.4,position=position_dodge(.4))
```

The following function would allow me to have all graphs I need stores in one object but no correct etiquette is displayed for different variable, only '.'

```
fig_fact<- map(data_fact,~ggplot(data_fact,aes(x=cluster,fill=.)) +
+geom_bar(position = position_dodge()))
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Also it's polite to provide a reproducible example when asking questions on SO and using `dput()` to provide your data in consumable format to us.

Comment: "Is it possible" is a bad question for stack overflow. The answer is  simply "yes". It even sounds like you know how to get started - loop, `is.numeric` or `is.character`, etc.

Comment: I would recommend writing short functions that make each type of plot that you want to make, e.g., a function for a numeric column, a function for a character column, etc. Then you make a main function that has a loop and tests each column for what it is and call the appropriate subfunction. Put all the plots in a list. You can find plenty of questions on Stack Overflow about putting mulltiple ggplots on one page.

Comment: Also, do you mean "loop over rows"?